# Page break from subreport is missing from exported PDF

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2014

I'm stuck with SQL 2014 because reasons. I have a subreport with this structure:

[image]

The intention is to have a page break before each table of parts destined for the same warehouse. This works perfectly when I view the report in Report Builder or SSRS. But when I export to PDF, the break before the first warehouse is missing, as if I had selected BreakLocation "Between" instead of "Start."

Is this a known issue? What's the workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a workaround. I added a tiny row at the top of the subreport table, outside the group. The row simply contains an empty textbox. The row must not be hidden, but the textbox can be, so you could add some text to explain why it's there.

[image]

The rule seems to be that if the very first thing in a subreport is a page break, it will be discarded. But why this only affects PDF export remains a mystery.